# Grid plugin for elasticSearch with CRUD

Tags: jquery, gridview, elasticsearch

I have been looking quite abit for a plugin or UI that does this with elasticsearch (version 1.3):

```
define datasource, set query
```

and get all reasults in a nice grid that enables CRUD operations.

I've been looking into kibana but that only gets me grids for read only.

Anyone know something close to this?

Thanks :)